# Are there any ways to use Anaconda as a package manager which is the same as npm?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, package-managers

What I would like to do is to save all the dependencies to a file which is the same as `package.json` and when I go to another computer, I only have to do something like `conda install` to install all the dependencies of the project. Those packages will not be installed globally, only in the project folder. I know that I can create a virtual environment with `conda` but there is no file which contains the list of all the dependencies.

I search for that but cannot find any sufficient answers: [Is there a project file support like npm/package.json for Python's pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977128/is-there-a-project-file-support-like-npm-package-json-for-pythons-pip)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can absolutely do that. Complete instructions are [here](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#share-an-environment)

Specifically, once you have an environment setup in one machine, you can create a file with dependencies:

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

And then recreate it exactly in another machine with:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

Comment: In my experience this doesn't work in practice. Because the full conda environment file will contain so many version-specific packages, trying to recreate it on another machine (possibly with another OS) will likely fail (npm gets around this issue by having a difference between the package.json file and package-lock.json file). According to [conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually) though, using the flag `conda env export --from-history` will only export the "primary" dependencies, which should solve this.